# Code to read the dataset

Tags: java, decision-tree

Here I read the dataset and extracted the data lines(not the attributes) and print it.Next I need to sort the dataset.Now this is stored in an ArrayList.How to sort it?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 

{
    String filen, jsnfl;
    Customiseddata data = new Customiseddata();
    data.setAlgorithm("C4.5");
    data.setUserName("Dahlia");

    System.out.println("Enter the file name");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    filen = sc.nextLine();
    data.setFileName("input_files/" + filen);
    Mainclass main = new Mainclass();
    main.build(data);
}



public void build(Customiseddata data) throws Exception 
{
        int extension;
        String filename;
        filename = data.getFileName();
        extension = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        String extensionType = filename.substring(extension + 1,
                filename.length());
        if (extensionType.equalsIgnoreCase("csv")) 
        {
            readcsv(filename);
        }

        else if (extensionType.equalsIgnoreCase("arff")) 
        {
            readarff(filename);
        }
}
public void readarff(String filename) throws Exception
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int filesize, attributesize, c = 0, i;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    float v = 0;
    String s, line1;
    ArrayList<String> filelines;
    ArrayList<String> attributes;
    Customiseddata data = new Customiseddata();

    Arfffilereader arfffile = new Arfffilereader();
    Extractdata exdata = new Extractdata();
    exdata = arfffile.extractInputArff(filename);

    filelines = exdata.getFileLines();
    attributes = exdata.getAttributes();
    filesize = filelines.size();
    attributesize = attributes.size();
    data.setFilesize(filesize);
    System.out.println("Print the attributes");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    for (i = 0; i < attributesize; i++) 
            {
        System.out.println(attributes.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("\t");
    System.out.println("Print the filelines");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    for (int j = 0; j < filesize; j++) 
            {
        System.out.println(filelines.get(j));
    }
}
```

But after this I need to sort the dataset.

Comment: ...and what are you actually asking here?

Comment: Here I just read and print the dataset .But I want to sort the dataset.

Comment: Have you try to sort it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the elements of the list are `String`s and since `String` implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), sorting a list is as simple as:

```
Collections.sort(theList);
```

Note however that it will sort the list *in place*. If you don't want that, make a copy of the list and sort that copy.

Comment: If the list is continuous.What is the method?

Comment: What do you mean by continuous?

Comment: Example:5.1,4.9,8.6,7.5,1.4,.........Each column like this.I need to sort each column.How?

Comment: OK, so what is in the list exactly? These numbers as strings? You want to sort using the numeric value?

Comment: It may be any thing like earliest example,but numeric.

Comment: So what's the element type? `Number`? `Double`? Something else?

Comment: Element data type may be float.It's depends on datasets.

Comment: Well then, as long as your list elements implement `Comparable` you can use the above (`Float` implements it). If they do NOT, however, you'll need to either make them implement this interface, or write a `Comparator` and use `Collections.sort(theList, theComparator)`.